# Use Applescript to set a Music app playlist's View Options?

Tags: applescript, ventura, music.app

I'm trying to write an Applescript that lets me set up the view options for a playlist, instead of having to click "View (as songs) > Show View Options" and then clicking a bajillion checkboxes & sorting the columns.

I'm hoping for something like this, and I'm stuck:

```
tell application "Music"
    set thePlaylist to (get name of current playlist)
    
    set view options of thePlaylist to {show Grouping column:true, show Rating column:true, show Plays column:false}
end tell
```

I have a ton of playlists, so I'm trying to automate this with an Applescript rather than having to set each one up individually.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, but I found out today that playlist view information is stored in preferences/defaults for Music.app, so in `com.apple.Music` domain (`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Music.plist` file). It should be changed with Music.app not running and preferably using `defaults` instead of editing the file.

It contains keys looking like `PPr4:LIB:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"` where `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` is the library id and `YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY` is permanent playlist id.

For value dictionaries I found out the meaning of following keys:

- `viewModeForPlaylist` sets view (`Songs`/`Albums`/`Artists`/…), `4` is for `Songs`,
- `browseVisible` boolean for showing column browser,
- `browseHeight` its height,
- `browseColumns` its columns, `[8, 4, 3]` for `Genres`/`Artists`/`Albums`,
- `columnSets` for columns configuration including order. I didn't understand why there are two dictionaries, as only Songs view has columns, but all keys are self-explanatory.

Script to get playlist ids (and names) using swift:

```swift
#!/usr/bin/env swift

import iTunesLibrary

let library = try! ITLibrary.init(apiVersion: "1")
for playlist in library.allPlaylists {
  print([
    "name": playlist.name,
    "persistentID": String(playlist.persistentID.uint64Value, radix: 16),
  ])
}
```